# Networkservice.NSPluginConnectionFailedexception: the remote server returned an error 409 conflict

Tags: azure, virtual, opendaylight, system-center

I'm trying to connect the ODL VSEM provider plugin in SCVMM to the VTN coordinator. Currently i'm facing the 'conflict' problem which is not allowing the SCVMM connect to the VTN coordinator.

[image: vtncoserver_error]

If anyone worked on this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

Looks like I have created a controller configuration manually in the VTN coordinator while testing it and when I try to add the same controller IP address through the VMM network service, it is throwing the above error in the VMM.

After checking the /usr/local/vtn/var/tomcat/log/accesslog.txt, i'm able to figure out the root cause of this issue. Now I have removed the existing ODL controller in the VTN coordinator.

To check the list of controllers connected to VTN.
GET : https://vtncoserver:8082/vtn-webapi/controllers.json

To Delete the controller 
DELETE : https://vtncoserver:8082/vtn-webapi/controllers/